# R console on singularity container exits with code 130 when interrupting a command

Tags: r, containers, hpc

I'm trying to run R interactively from a singularity container on a HPC.

The R console behaves normally if executed like this:

```
singularity exec container.simg R
```

Since I need to run several R sessions, and I don't want to extract a container for each session (to speed up boot time and to avoid using too much disk storage), I decided to execute the container multiple times from the same instance using the `singularity instance` feature:

```
singularity instance start container.simg my_instance
singularity exec instance://my_instance R
```

The above command opens a R console. However, if I interrupt a command with ctrl-C, the console crashed with exit code 130. This does not occur if I open the console by executing the container directly.

I wouldn't expect this to happen, as halting a command with ctrl-C on a R console usually doesn't kill the console. I would like that the R console executed with `singularity exec instance://my_instance` would behave the same as the one executed with `singularity exec container.simg`, i.e. not killing the R session when halting a command with ctrl-C.

So far, I tried to remove my `~/.Rprofile` and to create the instance with the `--cleanenv` flag.